# Получение всех возможных комбинаций флагов

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты

Учу c#, у меня задачка для проверки метода: нужно создать все возможные комбинации флагов и каждый отправить метода-проверить результат.

Я попробовал сделать это через сложение флагов, но у меня очевидно даже не половина и не половина половины нужных мне значений:

```cs
// список всех флагов
List<UInt32> accesses = new List<UInt32>
{
    1,
    2,
    4,
    // тут будет n значений, 
    // т.к. используется не в одной проверке
};

//список проверяемых флагов
List<String> write_accesses = new List<String>
{
    "ReadOnly",
    "Hidden",
    "System", 
    // ... список флагов, на которые должен реагировать тестируемый метод
};

// два цикла, чтобы пройтись по всему списку флагов 
// у меня тут очевидно ошибка и не думаю 
// что стоит это делать в двух for'ах
for (int i = 0; i < accesses.Count; i++)
{
    //получаем сумму - комбинацию флагов
    UInt32 vfs_uint32_combination = accesses.ElementAt(index: 0) + 
                                    accesses.ElementAt(index: i);
    FileAttributes vfs_test_combination = (FileAttributes)vfs_uint32_combination;

    //узнаем, получим ли мы из метода true или false
    String compare_string = vfs_test_combination.ToString();
    Boolean it_does = false;
    foreach (String access in write_accesses)
    {
        String[] strings_as_array = compare_string.Split(separator: new[] {',', ' '});
        foreach (String s in strings_as_array)
        {
            it_does = s.Equals(value: access);
            if (it_does)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (it_does)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Мне кажется, что я даже не в том направлении копнул, подскажите, пожалуйста, куда мне стоит смотреть или что нужно сделать.

**уточняю**

у меня есть список флагов, мне нужно из него получить все возможные сочетания флагов. в примере два списка, т.к. он вырван из кода, в котором мне надо еще и узнать что я получил.

Comment: Из Вашего вопроса мало что понятно. Итак. у Вас есть два списка: один с числовыми значениями, другой со строковыми. Как они между собой связаны? "все возможные комбинации" - комбинации чего с чем? Сколько раз может повторяться элемент из каждого списка? Какие ограничения?

Comment: Вообще ничего не понятно. Ну возможно вы хотите рекурсию.

Comment: Загоните все варианты в список. Допустим их 5. Возьмем бинарное число 11111, то есть 31. Далее пройдя в цикле от 0 до 31 и переводя в бинарную форму вы получите все возможные комбинации (единички будут индексами для списка вариантов)

Comment: Можно взять перечисление с атрибутом [Flags](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=netframework-4.8). Оно как раз для этого предназначено.